# Why is my program using Perl's getc function not working properly?

Tags: perl, getc

I want to calculate the frequency of occurrence of chars in a message using Perl. For instance, if the char "a" appears 10 times in a message, then the frequency would be 10. To do this, I am reading the message from a FILE one char at a time using the [getc](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/getc.html) function. Here's the snippet I have written. It's very basic, I know. But when I compile, I get an error:

Details:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $input=$ARGV[0];

open(INPUT,"<$input");

while(<INPUT>
{
 my $c=getc(INPUT);
 print $c."\n";
}

close(INPUT);
```

I get the below error when I try to compile it:

`Use of uninitialized value in print at AccessChar.pl line 13, <INPUT> line 1.`

I am not able to figure out, what's wrong with this script. Could someone help me out with this?

I have even tried using `getc` INPUT instead of `getc(INPUT)`. I don't think I need to include any other packages while running this script.

Comment: You've got a syntax error in that snippet (in the `while` line).

Comment: `getc` not working ... Oh, yes it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mixing the file read operator (`< ... >`) with `getc` is a bad idea. It's not doing what you think it is.

Try putting some debug output into the program to see what's going on. I tested the program by running it on itself (`./getc getc`).

At the start of the `while` loop, the `<INPUT>` reads a line from your file and stores it in `$_`. You then use `getc` to read the next character from the file. That will be the first character from the second line of your file (probably a newline character - which is likely to be the only character on that line).

The next time round the loop, the `<INPUT>` reads the next line of input. That's the `use strict` line. The `getc` reads the next character which is the 'u' from `use warnings`.

And so it continues to the end of the file. The `<INPUT>` reads a line and then the `getc` reads the first character from the next line.

That's not what you want at all. If you want to read a character at a time then you just need the `getc`.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $input = shift;

open(my $file, '<', $input);

while (defined(my $c = getc $file)) {
  print "$c\n";
}
```

Another alternative would be to just use `< ... >` and split each line as you read it.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $input = shift;

open(my $file, '<', $input);

while (<$file>) {
  foreach my $c (split //) {
    print "$c\n";
  }
}
```

But mixing the two approached is never going to work.

Answer (score 5):

```
while (<INPUT>)
```

will read a whole line from `INPUT` at each iteration of the loop. If you want to process that file handle one char at a time, it is not the right construct to use.

Try something like:

```
my $c;
while (defined($c = getc(INPUT))) {
  print $c, "\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It works :) I like your idea. Since getc returns an undef value on Error or EOF, we can use defined function. Interesting!

Answer (score 1):

Just for a little TIMTOWTDI:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

local $/;
my %chars;

$chars{$_}++ for split //, <>;

print Dumper \%chars;
```

which works as long as the file isn't too large to slurp; if it is the read and split each line. Usage:

```
$ count_chars.pl file_to_read
```